# Typehinting for "default" object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'll set up this question with two examples:

```
interface MyInput {
   reqString: string,
   reqNumber: number,
   optString?: string
}

const defaultValues: Partial<MyInput> = {
   reqString: "hello",
   optString: "goodbye"
};

// This gives an error for the reqNumber property: 
// Types of property 'reqString' are incompatible
// Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to 'string'
const inputObject: MyInput = {
   ...defaultValues,
   reqNumber: 5
};
```

The above example has the benefit of providing type hints in my IDE when I am building the `defaultValues` object to ensure I am defining properties in `MyInput`. However, the `Partial<MyInput>` type labels all properties in `MyInput` as optional, the consequence of which is that `inputObject` is not recognized as having defined all required properties in `MyInput` even though it actually has.

Here is a second example of the same scenario:

```
interface MyInput {
   reqString: string,
   reqNumber: number,
   optString?: string
}

// This has no type hints to ensure it follows the type of MyInput
const defaultValues = {
   reqString: "hello",
   optString: "goodbye"
};

// This does not give an error anymore
const inputObject: MyInput = {
   ...defaultValues,
   reqNumber: 5
};
```

Now, this will compile and `inputObject` is known to fully implement `MyInput`. However, I don't get any type hinting for `defaultValues`.

I know that I could use the type `Pick<MyInput, 'reqString' | 'optString'>` as the type for `defaultValues`, but then I constantly have to update that if I ever want to add more properties to the default object.

**Is there a way to dynamically type `defaultValues` such that it defines a subset of the properties of `MyInput` (with type safety) while *also* being recognized in `inputObject` as defining the missing required properties?**

Comment: You need to enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` for your first example to work, because optional properties are typed as `prop?: T | undefined`, but if you have the compiler option enabled, it is `prop?: T`. The `T | undefined` is why TypeScript is not happy (it could be undefined).

Comment: @kelly: This will still not override the way how `Partial` in TS works!

Comment: @SanthoshJohn Well it does; it fixes their original error but now you get a new error: https://tsplay.dev/NakZEW

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for, but when you want to extract something along with the types, you must have to use the `required` property in the inherited (not literally) one. I still think using `Omit` with this solution will also solve the issue with `required` properties, but will end up having keys to be specified every time like `Pick`.

By the way, there is no need to update anything in the `tsconfig.ts` file as well. It will work with the default settings that come installed along with TS installation.

```
// creates a dynamic type from the original
type DynamicType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

// this is your original
interface MyInput {
  reqString: string,
  reqNumber: number,
  optString?: string;
}

// this is a new const created
const defaultValues: DynamicType<MyInput> = {
  reqString: "hello",
  reqNumber: 105
};

// this is where you've utilised it
const inputObject: DynamicType<MyInput> = {
  ...defaultValues,
  reqNumber: 101
};
```

Comment: The type for `defaultValues` is no different from just `MyInput`.

Comment: @smac89: Yes! But, the user was bothered about type safety and fields to show, which is happening now. As I've explained the question itself feels like a circular dependency (pun intended!), I thought it would be a good candidature for at least heading him in the right direction rather than no one answering at all.  Also, in my first paragraph itself, I have explained what could be the more accurate solution for me!